# Running jest from maven with frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jestjs

The docs for jest seem to all assume that we're familiar with the whole yarn/npm/node ecosystem (I'm a java guy, so not so much).

I've got the following in my `pom.xml` for running webpack. I just don't know how to extend this so that mvn test will run unit tests in jest

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and npm</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <nodeVersion>v10.11.0</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>6.4.1</npmVersion>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>webpack build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>webpack</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>test</arguments>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <CI>true</CI>
                </environmentVariables>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are using npm with jest for testing and this is the configuration:

```
<execution>
    <id>run tests</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <arguments>test</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Build will fail if a test isn't satisfied

Comment: Maven build hangs once it runs the jest tests. Any idea why

Comment: @rogger2016 maybe your npm test runs a watch session so it doesn't return and it just wait?